# Can't exclude a directory pattern recursively

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get child items of a folder recursively. However the folder contains noise files and folder (actually, this is a Visual Studio project folder).

Here what I have:

```
$root = Get-Item C:\Projects\MyProject

$allItems =  Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse -exclude "**\pkgobj\*"
```

However, `$allItems` still contains files and folder matching the paths.

What I did wrong?

To be more precise, I want to get both folders and files, but not the specified folder, and any of its descendant.

I also tried:

```
foreach($item in $allItems){
    if($item.FullName -notmatch "pkgobj") {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $item.FullName.Replace($root,'')

    }
}
```

But no more success

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Took me a moment to understand the issue. Its a tricky one.

`-exclude` only applies to basenames of items (i.e. `myfile.txt`),  not the fullname
(i.e. `C:\pkgobj\myfile.txt`) which you want.   So you can't use *exclude* here.

But there is a workaround using `Fullname` and `-notlike`

```
$root = "C:\Projects\MyProject"
$allitems = Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse | Where {$_.FullName -notlike "*\pkgobj\*"}
```

Comment: However, if you want to exclude large directories due to performance (like node_modules), this won't help since it will still recursively check everything and filter afterwards.

Comment: What about this ?
Get-ChildItem -Exclude exclude_dir | foreach { Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Include *.include  -Recurse -Exclude *.excludefile | foreach { echo $_ } }

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid where statements when you can for performance reasons. To simplify a previous answer.

```
Get-childitem -path c:\windows -exclude 'temp' | get-childitem -recurse
```

Comment: Thanks... but don't your query applies to top level folders only ? What about if there's a folder name `c:\windows\foo\temp\` ?